# Find files that were not accessed in the last x days

Tags: linux, find

how can i find all files that were not accessed in the last 10 days with extension ".png"?

This is a question of my homework but i'm not getting it right
[image]

I tried `find / -type f -mtime -10 -name "*.png"` but it's not right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `-atime` for access time and `+10` for greater than 10 days:

```
find / -type f -atime +10 -name "*.png"
```